# Question about coadjoint orbits of compact connected Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}.$ Denote by $\mathfrak{g}^*$ the dual space of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $r$ be an element of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ such that $G_r$ the stabilizer of $r$ under the coadjoint action is a maximal torus of $G$. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_r$ the coadjoint orbit of $G$ which pass through $r$.

$\mathcal{O}_r$ is endowed with a 2-form which is a symplectic form
$$\omega_\alpha(\hat{X},\hat{Y})= -\alpha([X,Y]), \alpha \in \mathfrak{g}^*, \quad X,Y, \in \mathfrak{g}. $$
Often it is more convenient to choose
an inner product $\langle . , . \rangle$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ to identify $\mathfrak{g}^*$ with $\mathfrak{g}$. Once such an inner product has been chosen, we can write the 2-form as
$$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −\langle \lambda, [X,Y] \rangle, \lambda, X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}.$$

If $G$ is semisimple, then we choose the killing form denoted $k$ to define $\omega$:
$$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −k(\lambda, [X,Y]).$$

> $\textbf{Question}$: In the case where $G$ is a compact connected Lie group (not necessarily semisimple), why does the 2-form
> $$\omega_\lambda(\hat{X},\hat{Y}) = −k(\lambda, [X,Y]), \lambda, X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}.$$
> defined using the killing form defines a symplectic form on thecoadjoint orbit $ \mathcal{O_r}$ of $G$ ?

Ps: This question appeared under bounty for 100 points here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563148/symplectic-form-of-a-coadjoint-orbit-of-a-compact-connected-lie-group but didn't receive any answer so far.

Comment: Could you please explain the notations $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi,  $\hat{X}$ are $\hat{Y}$ are tangent vectors  in 
$T_\lambda(\mathcal{O_r})$, which is identified with the set $\lbrace [Z,\lambda] , Z \in \mathfrak{g} \rbrace $.

Comment: The first formula $$\omega_\alpha(\hat{X},\hat{Y})= -\alpha([X,Y]), \alpha \in \mathfrak{g}^*, \quad X,Y, \in \mathfrak{g}.$$ is not clear. What is the relation between $X$ and $\hat X$?

Comment: If you indeed want to get an answer, please try to explain your notation....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I'm sorry I didn't add these  details in my post! In this formula $\hat{X}$ is a tangent vector of $T_\alpha(\mathcal{O}_r)$ , where $\hat{X}= \frac{d}{dt}\rvert_ {t=0} e^{-t X}\cdot\alpha$.

Comment: I will type an answer tomorrow  or on Tuesday.

Comment: For today: Write $\frak g=\frak z \oplus \frak s$,  $\frak g^*=\frak z^* \oplus \frak s^*$, where $\frak z$ is the center of $\frak g$, and $\frak s=[\frak g,\frak g]$ is the derived  Lie algebra.  Then the natural projection $\frak g^* \to \frak s^*$ induces an isomorphism of the symplectic varieties $G\cdot r$ and $G^{\rm ad}\cdot r_{\frak  s}$ and preserves the Killing form. Here $G^{\rm ad}=G/Z(G)$ , and $r_{\frak  s}$ denotes the projection of $r$ to $\frak s^*$. Note that ${\frak s}={\rm Lie}\,G^{\rm ad}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Lie}{Lie}
\newcommand{\g}{{\mathfrak g}}
\newcommand{\z}{{\mathfrak z}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\mathfrak s}}
\newcommand{\O}{{\mathcal O}}
\newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}
\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde}$
Let $G$ be a connected compact Lie group, and let $\g$ denote its Lie algebra.
Write $\z$ for the center of $\g$ and set $\s=[\g,\g]$, which is a semisimple Lie algebra.
Then
$$ \g=\z\oplus\s.$$

Write $Z=Z(G)^0$ (the identity component of the center of $G$), $\ \wt S=[G,G]$, $S=G/Z(G)$.
Then $Z$ is a torus, whereas  $\wt S$ and $S$ are semisimple Lie groups.
We can identify
$$ \z=\Lie Z,\quad \Lie S=\s=\Lie\wt S.$$

The group $G$ acts on $\g$ by adjoint representation.
Moreover, $G$ acts on $\g$ via the canonical surjective homomorphism
$\pi\colon G\to S$.
We write
$$ g\cdot X=s\cdot X,\quad\text{where} \ g\in G,\ s=\pi(g)\in S,\ X\in\g.$$

We write an element $X\in \g$ as
$$ X=X_\z+X_\s\ \quad \text{with}\ X_\z\in\z,\ X_\s\in \s\,.$$
Then
$$g\cdot X=X_\z+g\cdot X_\s=X_\z+s\cdot X_\s\,.$$

Let $\g^*$ denote the dual space for $\g$.
Then
$$\g^*=\z^*\oplus \s^*.$$
For $r\in \g^*$ we may write
$$r=r_\z+r_\s\quad\text{with}\ r_\z\in\z^*, \ r_\s\in \s^*.$$
Then for $g\in G$ we have
$$g\cdot r=r_\z+g\cdot r_\s=r_\z+s\cdot r_\s\,.$$

Let $X\in\g$, $\ X=X_\z+X_\s\,$. Then $[X_\z\,,X_\s]=0$.
It follows that
$$\exp -tX=(\exp -tX_\z)\cdot( \exp -tX_\s) \quad\text{with}\
\exp -tX_\z\in Z,\ \exp -tX_\s\in\wt S,$$
whence
$$(\exp -tX)\cdot \alpha=\alpha_\z+(\exp-t X_\s)\cdot \alpha_\s\quad
   \text{for}\ \alpha=\alpha_\z+\alpha_\s\in \g^*.$$
Write
$$ \wh X=\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(\exp -tX)\cdot \alpha.$$
Then $\wh X=\wh{X_\s}$, where
$$ \wh {X_\s}=\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(\exp -tX_\s)\cdot \alpha_\s.$$

For $r=r_\z+r_\z \in\g^*$ write $\O_r=G\cdot r$, $\ \O_{r_\s}=S\cdot r_\s\,$. Then
$$ \O_r=r_\z+S\cdot r_\s=r_\z+\O_{r_\s}\,.$$
Thus for $\alpha=g\cdot  r\in \O_r$ we have
\begin{equation}\label{e:*}
 T_\alpha(\O_r)\cong T_{\alpha_\s}(\O_{r_\s}).\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}

Consider the adjoint representation
$$\ad\colon \g\to\mathfrak{gl}(\g),\quad (\ad X)\cdot Y=[X,Y].$$
For $X=X_\z+X_\s\in\g$ we have $\ad X=\ad X_\s\,$.

Consider the Killing form
$$ k\colon \g\times\g\to{\mathbb R}, \quad
(X,Y)\mapsto \Tr\!\big ((\ad X)\cdot (\ad Y)\big).$$
Then
$$ k(X,Y)=\Tr\!\big ((\ad X_\s)\cdot (\ad Y_\s)\big)=k(X_\s\,,Y_\s).$$

For $\lambda \in\g$, we define a skew-symmetric form on $T_\alpha(\O_r)$ by
$$\omega_\lambda(\wh X,\wh Y)=-k(\lambda,[X,Y]).$$
Since $[X,Y]=[X_\s\,,Y_\s]$, for $\lambda=\lambda_\z+\lambda_\s$ we have
$$\omega_\lambda(\wh X,\wh Y)=-k(\lambda,[X,Y])
  =-k(\lambda_\s,[X_\s\,,Y_\s])=\omega_{\lambda_\s}(\wh{X_\s}\,, \wh{ Y_\s\, }\,).$$

We can identify the tangent spaces
$T_\alpha(\O_r)$  and $T_{\alpha_\s}(\O_{r_\s})$ by \eqref{e:*}.
Then the formula above is probably what you need.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer @Mikhail Borovoi.